# Cluster Configuration - Worker Nodes

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, cpu-architecture, hyperthreading

I am beginner in cluster configuration. I know in our cluster we have types of worker nodes:

16  x  4TB Disks
128 RAM
2 x 8 Core CPUs

12  x  1.2 TB Disks
256 RAM
2 x 10 Core CPUs

I am confused about the configuration. What does mean 2 x 8 cores? It means 2 processor with 8 physical core each? So if my processor are hyperthreading i will have 2 X 8 X 2 = 32 virtual cores?
And 12 x 1.2 TB means, 12 disks with 1.2 TB each?

Comment: That seems about right. However, YOU should know what your cluster is made of, not us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually 2x 8 Core CPUs, means, that you have 2 physical chips on your motherboard, each having 8 Cores. If you enable hyperthreading, you then have 32 virtual cores.

The amount of disks is either the way, like you stated it, or its the number of nodes. Then you have 16 nodes with 4TB disk.... and 12 nodes with 1.2TB disk ....

I am just wondering, how someone can get to this hardware, not knowing what it means. Can you send me some nodes? :)

Comment: I really agree with you. The customer pass me this configuration and i ask him some questions about the cluster. No answers.. :)